# Best practice to have big video in website that play smoothly in slow connection

Tags: html, video, web

I'm working on a website and I want to add long videos (1.5 hours), for now the video format is in mp4. But it's okay to convert it to any other format. I found about 3 ways to put video, embed it or make it as streaming or progressive download. I don't know which one works good in my country with slow connection (only 1.5 mbps on average). I've researched through internet and many actually said that progressive download is best. But some friends here suggest to embed the video. Can anyone help me on making this decision? and give me the reason as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It's always a better idea to go for progressive download for slow connections. Living in a country where internet connection speed is never reliable and never over 2 mbps(India), I find that people prefer to start the video download in the player and then pause it till it loads fully. Progressive downloads allows this and lets them replay the downloaded video again and again without the need of a re-download. This is not possible in a streaming download, which relies on providing optimally encoded file depending on connection.

Embedding video is a different concept where you upload video on video streaming site like youtube or vimeo and use a piece of code so that users can play it on their browsers while they are on your site and never skip to vimeo/youtube unless they want to do that explicitly. Here the video request is served by youtube/vimeo and not your server.

Embedding is better if you want to save load on your web server. But if that is not a problem go for progressive download on your web server.

**EDIT:**
As per W3C definition,

> "Embedded content is content that imports another resource into the
>   document, or content from another vocabulary that is inserted into the
>   document."
>   http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#embedded-content-2

Essentially, any multimedia website that enables you to see the HTML of the content is technically "embeddable"
One site that allows you to embed almost anything from anywhere on web is http://embed.ly/embed

Comment: Sorry. Maybe it's annoying. But I thought embed video is where we just put the video on the website using the tag <video> so that the video is just there in the page, because what I heard is that taking longer time to upload the web page in browser.

Answer (score 1):

As a completely out-of-the box approach, could you upload it to YouTube? Then you can let them worry about device compatibility, streaming it to users, you get to use their CDN, and they optimise video for the connection that is available.

If you don't want it to be public, you can upload it as "Unlisted" so nobody can find it, and you can also create a [custom player](https://developers.google.com/youtube/getting_started) using their JS API if you wish, to remove controls, links to YouTube, etc.