# Why is Progresive Download more recommended than adaptive streaming? How to implement this in our website?

Tags: video, web

I want to add long video to my website (about 1.5 hours), but the problem is I live in low speed internet connection (only 1.5 mbps) country. I got the idea about the comparison between streaming and progressive download but I can't find on the internet any comparison for adaptive streaming and progressive download. I wonder what are the advantages and disadvantages of using those technics? How to implement it in our website, I mean in terms of encoding, video format, and implement it in our codes? Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best practice to have big video in website that play smoothly in slow connection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21496058/best-practice-to-have-big-video-in-website-that-play-smoothly-in-slow-connection)

Answer (score 0):

Progressive download is more widely supported. It will work on must devices/browsers/os. Adaptive streaming is generally a better solution for long form content, but it is more fragmented and difficult to implement server side. You need to supply a HLS version for iOS. smoothing streaming or HDS for PC, etc.